# How to run a command on file system change in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio, automation

I use a tool for validating JavaScript syntax, called JavaScriptLint (javascriptlint.com).
I'd like my Visual Studio to react to my save, CTRL-S and automatically trigger a command that runs javascript lint analyzing my current file.

Currently I do this using an external keycommand mapped to a key combination. But just hitting save and seeing instant output would be huge! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can accomplish this task by using a Visual Studio Macro and configuring to a key combination/command.

The following links should help:

[Can I have a macro run whenever I save a file in Visual Studio 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566746/can-i-have-a-macro-run-whenever-i-save-a-file-in-visual-studio-2005)

[Visual Studio Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967.aspx)

[Assigning a Keyboard Shortcut to Macro in VS](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/8)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[JSLint for Visual Studio 2010](http://jslint4vs2010.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Features:...Analyze JavaScript on Save

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking for a way to run any generic command. I'm actually not using JsLint (I use javascriptlint). Any clues?